# Python list : How to sort by timestamp? ( App Engine related )

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have ten entities in my Feed model ( this is an App Engine model)

```
class Feed(db.Model):
  sometext = db.StringProperty()
  timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

list_of_keys = ["key1","key2","key3".... "key10"]
```

so i call my entities using db.key() method:

```
feeds = db.keys(list_of_keys)
# this loop below prints the feed 
for feed in feeds:
  print humanizeTimeDiff(feed.timestamp) 

# humanizeTimeDiff is a function to change the raw timestamp into a human friendly
# version: eg-> 10 mins ago, 20 seconds ago
```

but now, how do I sort the feeds according to timestamp? ( I want the newest feeds at the top and the oldest ones at the bottom)

any sort function I can use on the raw timestamp? ( my rough plan is to sort according to the raw timestamp, then humanize the time difference )

PS: I don't plan to use GQL query to query my entities according to timestamp, because I get my input in the form of a list of keys. And using db.key() is a faster method.

hope I supplied enough info. wish to hear your thoughts/solutions.

Answer (score 10):

```
import operator

   ...

for feed in sorted(feeds, key=operator.attrgetter('timestamp'), reverse=True):
   print humanizeTimeDiff(feed.timestamp)
```